# Using selected for Dynamic options in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having a dynamic list of data which i am showing by dropdownlist.
But i want one those to be selected when the user enters the page.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <select ng-model="item1" style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
                    <option style="text-indent:30%" ng-repeat="item1 in IdeaMonthList"  value="{{item1}}" >{{item1}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is how i am making the dropdown list.

```
var IdeaMonth=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"]
 $scope.IdeaMonthList=IdeaMonth;
```

This is my array of months.By deafult when the user enters this page the current month should be selected in dropdownlist.

Using  we can choose the option for static option.
How to do it for Dynamic options

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <select ng-model="item1" style="width:50%;text-align:center;" ng-options="item for item in IdeaMonthList">
    </select>   
    </div>
</div>


var IdeaMonth=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"]
$scope.IdeaMonthList=IdeaMonth;
$scope.item1 =$scope.IdeaMonthList[new Date().getMonth()];
```

Plunker --  http://plnkr.co/edit/8dZXycSTYhQOog12FpEK?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Use **ngOptions** in angularjs.

> The ngOptions attribute can be used to dynamically generate a list of
>    elements for the  element using the array or object
>   obtained by evaluating the ngOptions comprehension expression.

```
<select ng-model="item1" ng-options="item for item in IdeaMonthList" style="width:100%;text-align:center;"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <select ng-model="item1" style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
                <option style="text-indent:30%" ng-repeat="item in IdeaMonthList"  value="{{item}}" >{{item}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>


var IdeaMonth=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"]
$scope.IdeaMonthList=IdeaMonth;
$scope.item1 =$scope.IdeaMonthList[new Date().getMonth()];
```

Comment: when html pages are rendered,IdeaMonthList is poopulated and 1st element is getting loaded.any how i need to use the selected keyword in option for the current month when ideaMonthList get populated.

Answer (score 0):

I think change your ng-model name

```
<select ng-model="selected" style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
```

And your JS File:

```
$scope.selected =$scope.IdeaMonthList[new Date().getMonth()];
```